# Unity fade all UI elements which belong to one Canvas

Tags: unity, gui, ui-design

Like the question describes I want to fade out/in all UI-Elements belonging to a parent canvas.

So things I got are :

- A World-Canvas which contains multiple UI-Items
- A script which can fade one color depending how close my cursor comes to that item

Things I want :

- A script which can fade my whole canvas without attaching each single Element with a color property to it

Thoughts :

- This would most likely work with a script which searches all Text children and Image children of the canvas, but I think that would be rather poorly performing code

I'm totally fine if there is no better solution as the mentioned one, but I would be annoyed if I implement it that way and there is a simple trick I don't know about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use a Canvas Group component on the top level canvas. It has an Alpha property that you can easily modify with a script.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html

Comment: That's great I totally missed that!